# Javascript function name in variable

Tags: javascript

**Hi guys!**

Could you please help me with the function beloW?
Code executes as planned, but as soon as i replace the 'SLL' string below with a variable, I get error.

- This works fine:       x = 'SLL'
- This does not work:    x = schemename  (assuming i define var schemename = 'SLL' earlier in the code)

Please see code below

```
function sll() {
    return 'got it';
}

var mySchemes = {
    SLL: sll
};

x = 'SLL';
mySchemes[x]();
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you post more code?

Comment: This code isn't formatted correctly... you have an opening function brace with no closing brace... is there something else missing?

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with using `var schemename = 'SLL'`. Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Why would ever want to do something like this?

Comment: I've tried to clean up the code based on what I think OP was asking

Comment: Please show us the actual code that is *not* working, the one with `schemename`.

Comment: Based on what you said, the only reason this would break is if you failed to define the `schemename` variable correctly, in a scope accessible to this code.

Comment: Probably defining schemename outside of scope or after it is being used  or something like that. Nothing wrong with what is shown

Comment: @Zydnar that has nothing to do with anything in question ...quotes are optional when no special characters in property name

Comment: @Zydnar also, you wrote "parentheses" when you meant "quotation marks"... please try to be clearer with your language

Comment: @user38101501 What error are you receiving? The only thing throwing an error (in strict mode) is undefined x. But for that you simply have to initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to run the code?  You can run the code right here on StackOverflow and see that it's running fine.  The one issue you *could* be having is if 'use strict' is being enforced, in which case you need to define `x` explicitly.

```js
function sll() {
    return 'got it';
}

var mySchemes = {
    SLL: sll
};

var x = 'SLL';
console.log(mySchemes[x]());
```